# Hover-effect on a :before class doesn't work as expected

Tags: css

I have realized a dropdown menue with a triangle at the top like this:

[image: regular view]

Now, when the cursor only rolls over the triangle it looks like this:

[image: rollover triangle]

But if the cursor is over the div the rollover-effect for both gets triggered like this:

[image: rollover div]

I want the hover-effect for both elements triggered, when the cursor moves over the triangle as well. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

This is my CSS:

```
.msg_archivedropdown {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    left: 40px;
    top:0%;
    background-color: #659DBD;
    z-index: 100;
    display:none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;  
}
.msg_archivedropdown:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    left:-7px;
    top:0px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid #659DBD;
}
.msg_archivedropdown:hover::before {
    border-right:7px solid #fff;
    color: #659DBD;
}
.msg_optiondropdownpoint {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.msg_optiondropdownpoint:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #659DBD;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a (partially) working example complete with the minimum amount of html so we can see what is going on?

Comment: With an half hour of work. I thaught that its something simple which i overlooked. The problem is that the rollover-effect of "Unterhaltung löschen" doesn´t get triggered when the cursor is over the "triangle", but it should be like in the 3. picture.

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer Hi can you add your html code here. so i can help to solve your problem.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a gradient to fake the empty space on the left. Then position your ::before element just inside the parent. Just keep in mind that you need to double the padding on the left to complete the visual trick:

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/team/Orbis/pen/ZwGvOK?editors=1100)

HTML:

```
<div class="parent-element">
    <p>
    I have reset the sensors to scan for frequencies outside the usual range. By emitting harmonic vibrations to shatter the lattices. We will monitor and adjust the frequency of the resonators. He has this ability of instantly interpreting and extrapolating any verbal communication he hears. It may be due to the envelope over the structure, causing hydrogen-carbon helix patterns throughout. I'm comparing the molecular integrity of that bubble against our phasers.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent-element{
    background:deeppink;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, deeppink calc(100% - 16px), rgba(0,0,0,0) 10%);
    padding:16px;
    padding-left:32px;
    width:320px;
    border-radius:4px;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    margin:48px auto;
}
.parent-element:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(to left, deepskyblue calc(100% - 16px), rgba(0,0,0,0)  10%);
}
.parent-element::before{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0 solid transparent;
    border-top-width: 16px;
    border-bottom-width: 16px;
    border-right: 16px solid deeppink;
    top:calc(50% - 8px);
    left:0px;
}
.parent-element:hover::before{
    border-right: 16px solid deepskyblue;
    pointer-events:auto;
}
```